# How to get access to SQlite ID autoincrement?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm using SQlite to keep my RecyclerView data.

I know that I can store the ID in an additional array or edit my adapter etc to get access to RecyclerView item's data when clicked, but this means in fact we have to duplicate SQlite ID.

Is there a correct solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you are looking for is **rowid**. You select it as you would do with any other column.

```
SELECT rowid, * FROM yourtable
```